# datatable sum column and concatenate rows using LINQ and group by on multiple columns

Tags: vb.net, linq, datatable

I Have a datatable with following records

```
ID   NAME     VALUE    CONTENT
1    AAA       10      SYS, LKE
2    BBB       20      NOM
1    AAA       15      BST
3    CCC       30      DSR
2    BBB       05      EFG
```

I want to write a VB.NET/LINQ query to have a output like below table: -

```
ID   NAME     SUM    CONTENT (as CSV)
1    AAA       25    SYS, LKE, BST
2    BBB       25    NOM, EFG
3    CCC       30    DSR
```

Please provide me LINQ query to get the desired result. Thanks.

I have tried concatenation using below query

```
Dim grouped = From row In dtTgt.AsEnumerable() _
                                Group row By New With {row.Field(Of Int16)("ID"), row.Field(Of String)("Name")} _
                                Into grp() _
                            Select ID, Name, CONTENT= String.Join(",", From i In grp Select i.Field(Of String)("CONTENT"))
```

Comment: What you have tried? As a hint, you need `GroupBy`.

Comment: We're not here to write your code for you. We're here to help you fix your code if it doesn't work. If you have no code then there's nothing for us to help with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers.
However, I have managed to get the desired result using simple code (Without LINQ): -

```
    Dim dt2 As New DataTable
            dt2 = dt.Clone()
            For Each dRow As DataRow In dt.Rows
                Dim iID As Integer = dRow("ID")
                Dim sName As String = dRow("Name")
                Dim sContt As String = dRow("Content")
                Dim iValue As Integer = dRow("Value")

                Dim rwTgt() As DataRow = dt2.Select("ID=" & iID)
                If rwTgt.Length > 0 Then
                    rwTgt(0)("Value") += iValue
                    rwTgt(0)("Content") += ", " & sContt
                Else
                    rw = dt2.NewRow()
                    rw("ID") = iID
                    rw("Name") = sName
                    rw("Value") = iValue
                    rw("Content") = sContt
                    dt2.Rows.Add(rw)
                End If
            Next
```

Answer (score 0):

This query will give you the expected output:-

```
Dim result = From row In dt.AsEnumerable()
             Group row By _group = New With {Key .Id = row.Field(Of Integer)("Id"), 
                          Key .Name = row.Field(Of String)("Name")} Into g = Group
             Select New With {Key .Id = _group.Id, Key .Name = _group.Name,
    Key .Sum = g.Sum(Function(x) x.Field(Of Integer)("Value")), 
    Key .Content = String.Join(",", g.Select(Function(x) x.Field(Of String)("Content")))}
```

Comment: @GLSOFTINDIA -  You're welcome. At SO, you can just accept\ upvote the answer to thank user, see how:- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work